# Stay in the same django template after a request.POST

Tags: django, django-views

I'm having problems with the return after doing a POST request in Django.
I have a template that shows information in a table  after doing POST request, in that table I have a button that opens a modal where I can Update the information of the table, I can do the update without problems, but after that I want to do nothing, in other word stay on the same page with the modal open, but when I return an `HTTPresponse()` this gives me a blank page

Comment: did you try `return HttpResponseredirect(request.path)`

Answer (score 0):

you must make this request with ajax, so your page will not have reload

Comment: The id of my form is a value passed from a templet `<form id={{number}}></form> how can I call the form with it ID, same goes for the input